# Алгоритм раскраски ребер графа

Tags: алгоритм, графы

Дан список ребер ациклического неориентированного графа. Необходимо найти оптимальную раскраску (т.е. использовать минимальное количество цветов) ребер графа такую, чтобы никакие два смежных ребра не имели один и тот же цвет. Подскажите оптимальный или эффективный алгоритм для решения.

Comment: Приведите к раскраске вершин (т.е. постройте граф, вершины которого соответствуют ребрам исходного, а ребра - соединяют смежные ребра исходного графа), а уж там решений - [полон интернет](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B0&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:ru:unofficial) :)

Answer (score 0):

Мое решение (низкая эффективность):
Заводим массив множеств, который будут содержать цвета ребер соответствующих вершин. Для каждого ребра проходим в цикле от 1 до максимальной степени графа, если видим, что вершину можно покрасить в i-ый цвет, то красим, сразу выводим результат и выходим из цикла.